# Probability density for free gaussian wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability

I am doing an exercise where the wave function for t>0 is: $\psi (x,t) = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{4a^2(1+\frac{it}{\beta })}}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{4}}\sqrt{a} \sqrt{1+\frac{it}{\beta }}}  $ with $\beta =2m\frac{a^2}{\hslash}$ and $\Delta x\approx a$.

> *"At time zero the probability density is:*
> $$\mid \psi (x,0)\mid ^2 =\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2a^2}}}{a\sqrt{2\pi }}=G(x,a)$$
> *where we defined the gaussian $G(x;a)$ with width parameter $a$. What is the probability density for $t>0$. Express your answer in terms of the gaussian $G$ with a time-dependent width parameter $a(t)$. Give $a(t)$."*

So I proceed to calculate the probability density for t>0:

$\mid \psi (x,t)\mid ^2 = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2a^2(1+\frac{t^2}{\beta^2 })}}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{2}}a \sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{\beta^2 }}}$

Now i can consider $a(t)=a\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{\beta^2}}$ and rewrite the probability density,

$\mid \psi (x,t)\mid ^2 = \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2a^2(t)}}}{(2\pi)^{\frac{1}{2}}a(t)}$

My question, is this a correct way to fulfill the exercise or there is another form more convenient for a(t). Also the $G(x,0)$, i don't know exactly what to do with it, must be included in the probability density somehow?

Comment: yes, now is correct. Thanks.

Comment: It looks right. You know have a Gaussian whose variance a(t) is spreading over time so $|\psi(x, t)|^2=G(0, a(t))$.